Installing Ubuntu on another new PC
I want to make a Ubuntu bootable USB with my laptop(current system) to use it to install Ubuntu on a new case (another system) which I bought (and has 64bit CPU).
I searched out the internet, but I wasn't sure if there were for installing Ubuntu on another system. I just want to make a bootable USB for another PC without installing Ubuntu on my current system.
How to make a bootable Ubuntu USB for another system? (and I may have to mention that my current system which I have to use it to make the bootable USB, has 32bit windows 7)
Thanks for answering

See https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Rufus is a powerful tool for making bootable USB.
Download rufus from https://rufus.ie and you can make bootable USB with Ubuntu iso files.
